# How would you find that a date is how much percent more or less than another date?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, timespan

Consider you have 2 dates:

```
        var left = new DateTime(2012,10,05,13,30,00);
        var right = new DateTime(2012,10,05,13,31,30);
```

The fact is: right is 1,5 minutes more than left. If we talk in terms of MINUTES, it seems to me right is around 5% more than left DateTime. (As year,month,date,hour are EQUAL in between. But can be different as well.)

How can I calculate the that right is how much percent more or less than the left date, in terms of minutes?

Comment: A percentage is a ratio between two values. One value you have (1,5 minutes), what is the other?

Comment: I think OP means (31,5 - 30) / 30 = 5%

Comment: how did you calculate 5%? give us the formula

Comment: (1,5 minutes / 30 minutes) I thought. And took it like right is 5% percent more than left in terms of minutes. Maybe I think it incorrect? But that does not make sense. Now I see it :( It is true just for the MINUTES part.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the difference in minutes like this:

```
double difference = TimeSpan.FromTicks(right.Ticks).TotalMinutes - 
                             TimeSpan.FromTicks(left.Ticks).TotalMinutes;
```

You could do the following but I don't think the result would be very useful in displaying difference between two dates:

```
double percent = TimeSpan.FromTicks(right.Ticks).TotalMinutes / 
                          TimeSpan.FromTicks(left.Ticks).TotalMinutes * 
                          100 - 100;
```